# Choosing Database.Esqueleto SQL operators dynamically

Tags: sql, haskell, yesod, esqueleto

I want to create `Database.Esqueleto` queries dynamically based on data stored in the database (see `DynamicQuery Database.Persist` entity in the code snippet below). The code below compiles but it is not very elegant because of repeated definitions (`op` for Text field type, `op2` for Day field type, and `op3` for `Bool` field type).

Is it possible to write a more general function similar to `op` that could be used in all cases in the definition of `expr`?

Trying to reuse `op` for the Day field type where `op2` is used results in the following error message:

```
test.hs:68:46:
Couldn't match expected type `Text' with actual type `Day'
Expected type: EntityField (ItemGeneric backend0) Text
  Actual type: EntityField (ItemGeneric backend0) Day
In the second argument of `(^.)', namely `ItemInserted'
In the first argument of `op', namely `(mp ^. ItemInserted)'
```

The code snippet follows:

```
{-# LANGUAGE EmptyDataDecls    #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts  #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs             #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes       #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell   #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes        #-}

import Database.Esqueleto
import Database.Esqueleto.Internal.Sql
import Data.Time.Calendar
import Data.Text (Text)
import qualified Data.Text as T
import Database.Persist.TH
import Database.Persist.Sqlite hiding ((==.), (!=.), (>=.), (<=.))
import Control.Monad.IO.Class (liftIO)

import Enums
{- enumerated field types have to be in a separate module due to GHC
-- stage restriction. Enums.hs contains the following definitions:
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell   #-}
module Enums where
import Database.Persist.TH

data DynField = DynFieldName | DynFieldInserted | DynFieldActive deriving (Eq, Read, Show)

derivePersistField "DynField"

data SqlBinOp = SqlBinOpLike | SqlBinOpLtEq | SqlBinOpGtEq | SqlBinOpNotEq | SqlBinOpEq deriving (Eq, Read, Show)

derivePersistField "SqlBinOp"

-}


share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"] [persistLowerCase|
DynamicQuery 
    field DynField
    op SqlBinOp
    value Text
Item
    name Text
    inserted Day
    active Bool 
|]

safeRead :: forall a. Read a => Text -> Maybe a
safeRead s = case (reads $ T.unpack s) of
   [(v,_)] -> Just v
   _ -> Nothing

getItems dc = do

    select $ from $ \mp -> do
        where_ $ expr mp
        return $ mp ^. ItemId
    where
        value = dynamicQueryValue dc
        boolValue = case safeRead value of
            Just b -> b
            Nothing -> False
        dateValue = case safeRead value of
            Just dt -> dt
            Nothing -> fromGregorian 1900 1 1
        expr = \mp -> case dynamicQueryField dc of
            DynFieldName           -> (mp ^. ItemName) `op` val value
            DynFieldInserted       -> (mp ^. ItemInserted) `op2` val dateValue
            DynFieldActive         -> (mp ^. ItemActive) `op3` val boolValue
        op = case dynamicQueryOp dc of
            SqlBinOpEq -> (==.)
            SqlBinOpNotEq -> (!=.)
            SqlBinOpGtEq -> (>=.)
            SqlBinOpLtEq -> (<=.)
            SqlBinOpLike -> unsafeSqlBinOp " ILIKE "

        op2 = case dynamicQueryOp dc of
            SqlBinOpEq -> (==.)
            SqlBinOpNotEq -> (!=.)
            SqlBinOpGtEq -> (>=.)
            SqlBinOpLtEq -> (<=.)
            SqlBinOpLike -> unsafeSqlBinOp " ILIKE "

        op3 = case dynamicQueryOp dc of
            SqlBinOpEq -> (==.)
            SqlBinOpNotEq -> (!=.)
            SqlBinOpGtEq -> (>=.)
            SqlBinOpLtEq -> (<=.)
            SqlBinOpLike -> unsafeSqlBinOp " ILIKE "

main = runSqlite ":memory:" $ do
    runMigration migrateAll
    _ <- insert $ Item "item 1" (fromGregorian 2014 2 11) True
    _ <- insert $ Item "item 2" (fromGregorian 2014 2 12) False
    let dc = DynamicQuery DynFieldName SqlBinOpEq "item 1"
    items <- getItems dc
    liftIO $ print items
```

Comment: @KarthikVU, I have reviewed a number of your edits today... please provide a more accurate description for your edits than '*Small Changes*', which you added for *all* of the ones that I saw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the operators you gave on your example, it's just a matter of providing an explicit type signature.  The following works fine:

```hs
expr = \mp -> case dynamicQueryField dc of
    DynFieldName     -> (mp ^. ItemName)     `op` val value
    DynFieldInserted -> (mp ^. ItemInserted) `op` val dateValue
    DynFieldActive   -> (mp ^. ItemActive)   `op` val boolValue

op :: PersistField a => SqlExpr (Value a) -> SqlExpr (Value a) -> SqlExpr (Value Bool)
op = case dynamicQueryOp dc of
    SqlBinOpEq    -> (==.)
    SqlBinOpNotEq -> (!=.)
    SqlBinOpGtEq  -> (>=.)
    SqlBinOpLtEq  -> (<=.)
    SqlBinOpLike  -> unsafeSqlBinOp " ILIKE "
```

If any of the operators had more constraints on its arguments (e.g., `Num a`), then the approach above would force the whole `op` to have the union of all constraints.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! I tried to use the type signature of the operator (==.) which is `PersistField typ => expr (Value typ) -> expr (Value typ) -> expr (Value Bool)` but it gave a frightening compiler error. I didn't figure out how to restrict the type variable `expr` appropriately.